# Why does jQuery recommend putting <script> tags at the end of <body>?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Move jQuery to the end of body tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220956/move-jquery-to-the-end-of-body-tag)

I [notice](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=How_jQuery_Works&redirect=no) that jQuery nowadays seem to recommend both loading `jQuery.js` and also putting your own jQuery code at the end of `<body>` instead of `<head>`. Why is that? What are the advantages?

Comment: It's marginally faster on loading - but we're talking miniscule fractions of a second.

Comment: Scripts in the `<head>` slow down page download and rendering. Moving scripts to the end of the document gives the impression of much faster loading, because scripts are requested and executed when user already sees the page.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that heavily depends... on the browser, the size of the loaded scripts and the users internet connection. It may be a noticable difference with up to several seconds blank page if you are unlucky especially on mobile devices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not jQuery recommending it but some performance/usability gurus.

The reason is that downloading a script will stall the creation of your page and if your scripts are huge and/or the users connection is slow, the user will see a blank page for some time. If you put your scripts at the bottom, the browser can create the page and load the scripts afterwards, the user is not confronted with a blank page.
This however is only possible if you either have all stuff in `$(document).ready` (which means that this stuff is executed anyway only after the DOM is ready) and/or your scripts are independent from the dom in some way. Also you have to be aware of the order.
If you absolutely need to do some javascript things very early then you might not be able to move them to the end of the page or it simply might not be feasible to wait that long.